# Inno Setup SetupIconFile Resource Update Error: Icon File is invalid

Tags: windows-installer, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, ico

I want to customize the setup icons for my installer(Inno Setup). I've setup this line of code for that purpose:

```
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\myapp.ico
```

However, this error appears when I compile the installer:

[image]

What does this mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: Seems like the file you point is not a proper icon file. Could you share it with us? It may be JPG or other kind of bitmap with changed extension to ICO.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Download and install the latest build of Inno Setup fixed it for me.